# Rails text area saved to database then display

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a text area that a user can type in then with a button what they typed gets displayed. When they add spaces I get in error in the JavaScript though because its all not on the same line. Is there a way I can save the text with the html formatting such as /n?

```
$(button).click(function(){
    $(DisplayUserTextArea).html('<p> <%= @user.TextArea %> </p>');
});
```

This what happens when it runs on the site and its getting an error here because its spaced out.

```
$(button).html('<p> Test Text


TESTTTTTTT</p>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`$(DisplayUserTextArea).html('<p> <%= @user.TextArea.squish %> </p>');`

here is detail description [remove all whitespaces and new lines.](https://apidock.com/rails/String/squish)

This should work
Thank you

Comment: Still getting the same error because it's still parsing the JavaScript on a new line.

Comment: @ jrocc your question is not clear to me, i mean first you are saving the textarea content and then on button click you are displaying.? is it so?

Comment: Yes on the button click I am displaying what was saved from the text area.

Comment: `$(DisplayUserTextArea).html('<p> <%= @user.TextArea.squish %> </p>');`

try this, so far as i understand you don't want new lines and white spaces all.

Comment: i have changed the above answer as well .  :)